# sidebar double click instead of a single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with my left side bar, i need to have my sidebar populated  when it's clicked  but when i run my code i have to double click on my "show menu" to get my menu...what am i doing wrong?

```
       $(document).ready(function () {

       var slider_width = $('.menucont').width(); //get width automaticly
       $('#pollSlider-button').click(function () {
           if ($(this).css("margin-right") == slider_width + "px" && !$(this).is(':animated')) {
               $('.menucont,#pollSlider-button').animate({
                   "margin-right": '-=' + slider_width
               });

               $(".menucont").show();

               $(".showmenu").css("display", "none");
                               $(".hidemenu").show();



           } else {
               if (!$(this).is(':animated')) //perevent double click to double margin
               {
                   $('.menucont,#pollSlider-button').animate({
                       "margin-right": '+=' + slider_width

                   });
                   $(".showmenu").show();

                   $(".menucont").hide();
                   $(".hidemenu").css("display", "none");

               }
           }


       });
   });
```

i also have a fiddle URL
http://jsfiddle.net/6834Y/

any help would be greatful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set your div like this:

```
<div id="pollSlider-button" style="margin-right: 77px;">
```

Instead of:

```
<div id="pollSlider-button" style="margin-right: 0px;">
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/6834Y/1/

Comment: Thanks Robert for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

When you click first time

```
$(this).css("margin-right")
```

returns 0 sot it will enter else block in else you will execute the

```
$('.menucont,#pollSlider-button').animate({
                   "margin-right": '+=' + slider_width

               });
```

so when click next the menu show up.

you can change the if loop as below

```
if (($(this).css("margin-right") == slider_width + "px" && !$(this).is(':animated')) || $(this).css("margin-right") == "0px")
```

Comment: ohhhh thats right! fresh pair of eyes that what i needed. thanks